# How to delete a selected DataGridViewRow and update a connected database table?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tableadapter

I have a `DataGridView` control on a Windows Forms application (written with C#).

What I need is: when a user selects a DataGridViewRow, and then clicks on a 'Delete' button, the row should be deleted **and** next, the database needs to be updated using table adapters.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
    }                
}
```

Furthermore, this only deletes one row. I would like it where the user can select multiple rows.

Answer (score 93):

This code removes selected items of `dataGridView1`:

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
     {
         dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
     }
 }
```

Comment: In general it's not always safe to be modifying an object related to the object we are iterating over, also the indices might not be updated.

Comment: Best practices say to use a for loop instead of a foreach loop and iterate backward from the end. This helps you to preserve your index and avoid issues while editing during your iterations.

Comment: @Grungondola you should make a separate answer for this

Answer (score 22):

```
private void buttonRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
        if (oneCell.Selected)
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Removes rows which indexes are in selected cells. So, select any cells, and their corresponding rows will be removed.

Answer (score 10):

I have written the following code, please take a look:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
    if (!row.IsNewRow) dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
```

using the `Index` of the selected row still could work; see if the code below will do the trick:

```
int selectedCount = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;           
while (selectedCount > 0)
{
    if (!dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].IsNewRow)
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
    selectedCount--;
}
```

I hope this helps, regards.

Comment: thanks... the main problem I'm having now is saving to the database using tableadapters.

Comment: you need to provide more details on what is not working for you; I bet the best response you would get by starting a new question with a code snip which is causing troubles

Answer (score 4):

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumIndex == 10)// 10th column the button
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
    }                
}
```

This solution can be delete a row (not selected, clicked row!) via "e" param.

Comment: Why not use foreach instead? Ref to @Navid Farhadi's answer.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can use temp list for delete. for ignore row index change

```html
<pre>
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> wantdel = new List<int>();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        if ((bool)row.Cells["Select"].Value == true)
        wantdel.Add(row.Index);
    }

    wantdel.OrderByDescending(y => y).ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(x);
    });           
}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete multiple rows in datagrid, c#

parts of my code:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagrid1.SelectedRows)
        {
            //get key
            int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);

            //avoid updating the last empty row in datagrid
            if (rowId > 0)
            {
                //delete 
                aController.Delete(rowId);

                //refresh datagrid
                datagrid1.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index); 
            }  
        }
    }




 public void Delete(int rowId)
        {
            var toBeDeleted = db.table1.First(c => c.Id == rowId);
            db.table1.DeleteObject(toBeDeleted);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I usually delete checked rows by the user from a `DataGridView`, if you are associating it with a DataTable from a `Dataset` (ex: `DataGridView1.DataSource = Dataset1.Tables["x"]`), then once you will make any updates (delete, insert,update) in the `Dataset`, it will automatically happen in your `DataGridView`.

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record(s)", "confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = dgv_Championnat.RowCount -1; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dgv_Championnat.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value) == true)
                    {
                        Program.set.Tables["Champ"].Rows[i].Delete();
                    }
                }
                Program.command = new SqlCommandBuilder(Program.AdapterChampionnat);
                if (Program.AdapterChampionnat.Update(Program.TableChampionnat) > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Well Deleted");
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private: System::Void button9_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=password";
    MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
    conDataBase->Open();
    try 
    {
        if (MessageBox::Show("Sure you wanna delete?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons::YesNo) == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::Yes)
        {
            for each(DataGridViewCell^ oneCell in dataGridView1->SelectedCells)
            {
                if (oneCell->Selected) {
                    dataGridView1->Rows->RemoveAt(oneCell->RowIndex);
                    MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase1 = gcnew MySqlCommand("Delete from Dinslaken_DB.Configuration where Memory='ORG 6400H'");
                    cmdDataBase1->ExecuteNonQuery();
                    //sda->Update(dbdataset);
                }   
            }           
        }
    }
    catch (Exception^ex)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(ex->ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this command delete selected row when user selected in datagridview:

gvTest.Rows.RemoveAt(dvTest.CurrentRow.Index];

Answer (score 0):

have a look this way:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Sure you wanna delete?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{
  foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
  {
      bindingSource1.RemoveAt(item.Index);
  }
      adapter.Update(ds);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count>0)
{
    dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(dgv.CurrentRow.Index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this.dgvpurchase.Rows.Count>1)
{
    if(this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Index<this.dgvpurchase.Rows.Count)
    {
        this.txtname.Text = this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        this.txttype.Text = this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        this.cbxcode.Text = this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        this.cbxcompany.Text = this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        this.dtppurchase.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value);
        this.txtprice.Text = this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        this.txtqty.Text = this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        this.txttotal.Text = this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        this.dgvpurchase.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dgvpurchase.CurrentRow.Index);
        refreshid();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer, just naked code is not enough

Answer (score 0):

You delete **first** from the database and **then** you update your `datagridview`:

```
//let's suppose delete(id) is a method which will delete a row from the database and
// returns true when it is done
int id = 0;
//we suppose that the first column in the datagridview is the ID of the ROW :
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
   id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
if(delete(id))                               
   this.dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
//else show message error!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                ?BindingSource.EndEdit();
                ?TableAdapter.Update(this.?DataSet.yourTableName);
}

//NOTE:
//? - is your data from database
```

Exception no need ... or change with your own code.

CODE:
[image]

DB:
[image]

Example: [prntscr.com/p3208c](http://prntscr.com/p3208c)

DB Set:  http://prntscr.com/p321pw

Comment: Just do code and it will do the job.
Example: http://prntscr.com/p3208c

Answer (score 0):

```
   ArrayList bkgrefs = new ArrayList();
                    foreach (GridViewRow rowd in grdOptionExtraDetails.Rows)
                    {
                        CheckBox cbf = (CheckBox)rowd.Cells[1].FindControl("chkbulk");

                            if (cbf.Checked)
                            {
                                rowd.Visible = true;
                                 bkgrefs.Add(Convert.ToString(grdOptionExtraDetails.Data.Rows[rowd.RowIndex]["OptionID"]));

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                grdOptionExtraDetails.Data.Rows.RemoveAt(rowd.DataItemIndex);
                                rowd.Visible = false;
                            }


                    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - it may be useful to add some commentary about what the code you posted is doing to help the OP understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.YourGridViewName.SelectedRows)
{
    string ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=DESKTOPQJ1JHRG\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=smart_movers;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName =@Index", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Index", item.Index);
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (i != 0)
    {
        YourGridViewName.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Succefull!", "Great", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Failed!", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int count = dgvSchedule.SelectedRows.Count;

    while (count != 0) {
        dgvSchedule.Rows.RemoveAt(dgvSchedule.SelectedRows[0].Index);
        count--;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

//This worked for me. The datasource is a BindingList

```
private void DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left
      && e.ColumnIndex < 0
      && e.RowIndex >= 0
      && e.RowIndex < DataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
   {
      intRowHeader = e.RowIndex;
   }
}

private void DataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (intRowHeader.HasValue && e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
   {
      DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt((int)intRowHeader);
      intRowHeader = null;
   }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int j = dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j > 0 ; j--)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[j-1].Selected)
        dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(j-1);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It Work for me !

```
private: System::Void MyButton_Delete_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
    // Удалить столбец(Row).
    MydataGridView->Rows->RemoveAt(MydataGridView->CurrentCell->RowIndex);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

here is one very simple example:

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="#996633" 
       SelectedRowStyle-ForeColor="Fuchsia">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdateClick"/>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private readonly DataTable _dataTable;

    public _Default()
    {
        _dataTable = new DataTable();

        _dataTable.Columns.Add("Serial", typeof (int));
        _dataTable.Columns.Add("Data", typeof (string));

        for (var i = 0; ++i <= 15;) 
        _dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {i, "This is row " + i});
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        gvTest.DataSource = _dataTable;
        gvTest.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnUpdateClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (gvTest.SelectedIndex < 0) return;

        var r = gvTest.SelectedRow;

        var i = r.DataItemIndex;

        //you can get primary key or anyother column vlaue by 
        //accessing r.Cells collection, but for this simple case
        //we will use index of selected row in database.
        _dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(i);

        //rebind with data
        BindData();

        //clear selection from grid
        gvTest.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

you will have to use checkboxes or some other mechanism to allow users to select multiple rows and then you can browse the rows for ones with the checkbox checked and then remove those rows.