# DataGridView Removed rows cells still show up in code, even though removed from Grid

Tags: c#, winforms

So in my code, I have a delete button then when clicked will remove the selected rows from the Grid.

This appears to work at the UI level.

But when I had to rederive my data from the cells in the Grid, somehow the stuff I just deleted was still in there. I learned this as I was looping through line by line in debug mode.

My Base algorithm came from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084346/delete-selected-row-from-datagridview-and-update-db)'s first answer. 
Now I looked at the MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) about what RemoveAt actually does
Unfortunately, it wasn't very enlightening.

```
 Removes the row at the specified position from the collection.
```

Here is my code.

```
private void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  

        if (this.DataView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in DataView.SelectedRows)
            {
                DataView.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);

            }

        }

        refreshDataFromGrid();
    }
```

Now here is the part that derives the Data from what is in the Grid

```
    private void refreshDataFromGrid()
    {
        //if the rows in the gridview aren't empty copy them over to the String array in d.value
        for (int i = 0; i < DataView.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < DataView.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
            {
                if (DataView.Rows[i].Cells[j].ToString() != "")
                {
                    (DataViewParent as STS_Console.MenuItems.MenuItem).d.Value[i, j] = DataView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();

                }
            }                                                                                                       

        }

    }
```

I would be glad to provide screenshots or anything else as necessary, just ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, I needed to refresh the grid. like so

```
         DataView.Refresh();
```

I had originally assumed that refresh was needed for the UI. Since the UI was working I was confused as to why this was happening. But it is not just for the UI, its for reading any values from the DataGridView.