# Delete row in datagridview and database with C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagridview

I made a database and a program with a datagridview to show the database content.
Now I want to make a button to let users delete a row and delete it also in the database.

I tried the following solution which I found in Stackoverflow: [How to delete row datagrid..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105792/how-to-delete-row-datagrid-and-update-sql-database-c-sharp)

**But I get following Error:**
[image]

The error tells me that the type **SqlConnection** was not found.

**My whole code I've linked here:**[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DyA0fkM3)

```
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count == 0)
            return;

        string sql = "DELETE FROM ticket.support WHERE ID = @rowID";

        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("...."))
        using (SqlCommand deleteRecord = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
        {
            myConnection.Open();

            int selectedIndex = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, selectedIndex].Value);

            deleteRecord.Parameters.Add("@rowID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rowID;
            deleteRecord.ExecuteNonQuery();

            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
        }
```

Comment: i think u missed the reference `Imports System.Data.SqlClient`

Comment: where do I put the reference ?

Comment: u should put under this `using System.Windows.Forms;`, and use using instead import

Comment: You need to add the dll references. Refer this link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to System.Data.SqlClient.

In Visual Studio you can expand a project, right-click on References and click on Add Reference, navigate to the actual reference and add it to the project. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019

Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019

If a reference is missing, then you can download it via the [NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore).