# Delete Top Row from DataGridView Without Clicking

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewrow

I want to remove the first row from a datagridview before it loads in the form.
What I have at the moment is :

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridViewRow[0]);
```

This doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how I should adapt my code for this to work?

Comment: Before you load any data you have 0 rows, so you can't delete anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure data is loaded.  If you're unsure - debug, step through, and ensure there IS a row 0.

Then, try the following:

```
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[0]);
```

Further discussion on row removal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084346/how-to-delete-a-selected-datagridviewrow-and-update-a-connected-database-table).  Might give you some other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dataGridView1.DeleteRow(dataGridViewRow[0].RowIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try this one and apply it on your form load event.

```
if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the datagrid databound to a collection? If so, you could exlude the first element by doing something like this:

```
List<string> list = GetSomeData();
dataGridView1.DataSource = list.GetRange(1, list.Count-1);
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```