# Removing Uncheck values on datagrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid

I want to remove all the values that I have unchecked on data grid with a **Cancel** button.I know how to do it with the checked ones but how can I do it in the unchecked rows?

here is my code for the checkeded with the button **Proceed**

```
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE JobQuotations1
                                          SET TransactionStatus = @Done
                                         WHERE TransactionID = @Tid
                                        AND
                                        TransactionNum = @num", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Done", "Done");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tid", row.Cells[2].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", row.Cells[4].Text);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                LoadDataGrid();
            }

        }
```

Comment: what does `LoadDataGrid` do?

Comment: @Valentin id refresh the datagrid in my webpage.Show the new data.

Comment: You will probably want to move it outside the `foreach` so you will update after all database job.

Comment: Are you trying to remove unchecked item from a database or from the grid?

Comment: @Valentin yes I want to removed unchecked items in gridview

Comment: Have you read it? [How to delete a selected DataGridViewRow and update a connected database table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084346/how-to-delete-a-selected-datagridviewrow-and-update-a-connected-database-table)

Comment: @Valentin I tried to do this  `(!chkrow.Checked)` It's working but.It deletes two rows at the same time.

Comment: How are you removing the element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113569/discussion-between-rai-nalasa-and-valentin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this one `(!chkRow.Checked)` on my if statment and that all worked for me.

```
` foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[0].FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
            if (!chkRow.Checked)
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE JobQuotations1
                                          SET TransactionStatus = @Cancel
                                         WHERE TransactionID = @Tid
                                        AND
                                        TransactionNum = @num", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cancel", "Cancel");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tid", row.Cells[2].Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num", row.Cells[4].Text);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                LoadDataGrid();
            }

        }`
```